# Using javascript, how to auto focus after redirecting to other site?

Tags: javascript, dom, redirect

For example,  I want to redirect first to stackoverflow ask page, and focus on title input box.
To implement this, I made this function.

```
var redirectAndFocus = function (){
    window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");
    document.getElementById('title').focus();
}();
```

But Even page has been redirected, Nothing has happened like focus event.
Is there any way to this?
If not, Why It wouldn't be happened?

Comment: 1. Location changes are instant and statements after are not executed. 2. It is wishful thinking to try to execute something on another page after it loaded with a statement in the page that instigated the change. Apart from the issue of origin, it would be very bad if the script would for example submit your details to a hacker

Comment: Many duplicates here. Please search your title before asking

Comment: Thank you for answering my naive question.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it as.

```
window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#title") ;
```

Comment: That does not focus anything. Only scrolls to the ID